# How to redirect multiple domains from non-www to www in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I have 5 unique unrelated domains. In the  main domain (hosting package has root one with other domains in folders)  I need to redirect all non-www urls to www.  I used this code in my .htaccess file on the main domain:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.co.za
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.co.za/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It worked for the main domain, but now makes all my other domains (eg www.myothersite.com ) forward to an url like this:

```
//mysite.co.za/myotherdomain.com/home
```

How can I prevent this.

Answer (score 1):

Short and incl. **HTTPS**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this is:

```
# enable rewrite engine
RewriteEngine on
# if requested hostname does NOT start with "www."
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
# get hostname to %1 variable
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]+\.[a-z]+)
# prepend "www." to requested hostname and file
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you want to be more specific and only include certain domains, use:

```
# enable rewrite engine
RewriteEngine on
# if requested hostname does NOT start with "www."
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
# and if one of these hostnames, then get it to %1 variable
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(domain1\.com|domain2\.com|mysite\.co\.za)
# prepend "www." to requested hostname and file
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So in the `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(domain1\.com|domain2\.com|mysite\.co\.za)` line you would add all domains that need to be redirected.